# Control web page from http post or get

Tags: javascript, php, http, post, get

I'm usually OK at figuring out small little codes snips and what I need, but I'm kind of lost right now.

This is what I would like to do.  I will be running a simple WAMP server on a PC.  This will have a single webpage that shows weather/time/date.

Now what I want to be able to do, is using Tasker on Android to send a HTTP POST or GET to that webserver so it can change color of the font.

EG:  on Tasker I would assign a button to 192.168.1.10/index.php?color=FF33AA  and the computer running the webpage would get that info and change the text color to FF33AA.  I have lots of LED lights that are IR controled and they all work, but I want the clock/weather to sync it's colors to the LED's.

I have the webpage, sever, tasker all running.  What I can't figure out is how to make the page wait for a php get or post msg and then change the color to what is sent.

Thanks for any help in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome OP, Place some hint code. That code will help to find proper solution.

Comment: Couldn't get on what event you want what at which side.
May be on post method u need to use printwriter out.write() or similer

Answer (score 0):

You can write all the server side php code inside if condition like;

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){  do something } else {}
```